# Add class to all page elements with certain class after clicking at menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add and immediately remove class ".current" for all page elements with class ".chrome" after click at menu item with ".menu-item" class.

```html
<ul id="navigation">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#link-1">1</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#link-2">2</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#link-3">3</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#link-4">4</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#link-5">5</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#link-6">6</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#link-7">7</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#link-8">8</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#link-9">9</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please reword your question; I can't understand what you need.

Comment: Edited, now I think it is more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) from the jQuery documentation. To add a class, and then immediately remove it, you can use the following:

```
$('.menu-item').on('click', function() {  
    $('.chrome').addClass('current').removeClass('current');
});
```

Comment: Thank you guys, you are best!

Answer (score 0):

This is what i can think of reading what you've asked for.

to add class to everything after click

```
$(".menu-item").on("click",function(){
    //this is to add to all 
    $("*").addClass("current");
    //this is to add to all with class chrome
    $(".chrome").addClass("current");
});
```

to remove all

```
$(".menu-item").on("click",function(){
    //this is to remove all 
    $("*").removeClass("current");
    //this is to remove classes all from .chrome
    $(".chrome").removeClass("current");
});
```

both

```
$(".menu-item").on("click",function(){
    //add remove all
    $("*")$("*").addClass("current").removeClass("current");
    //add remove all from .chrome
    $(".chrome")$("*").addClass("current").removeClass("current");
});
```

Comment: `$(".chrome")$("*")` and `$("*")$("*")`?